# Why does my CSS media query break when navigating my rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm currently trying to make my site (spitball.io) responsive, using twitter bootstrap and css media queries. On the new iPhones, hiding elements using bootstrap's the xs, sm, md etc. breakpoints doesn't work. So, instead, I've been using the media query

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.iphone-disappear{display:none;}
}
```

To apply to elements I'd like to disappear when on a mobile device.
This works fine when I navigate to '/wads' from the landing page. However, when I go from another page on the app, back to '/wads' the query breaks, and I get a view similar to what the desktop view looks likes. See screenshots below.

[image: Good View][image: Bad View]

Comment: Why do you say that "On the new iPhones, hiding elements using bootstrap's the xs, sm, md"? Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">` in your head  tag? (http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

Comment: @AbM This was the answer btw. I'm using the bootstrap gem and I assumed that it included this meta tag, but I guess it didn't? Not sure but anyway, thank you!